# MySQL Workbench trigger giving #1064 error

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, mysql-workbench

My MySQL trigger is not working at all. MySQL Workbench added some things other than my original query, but I'm still getting errors:

[image: query and error]

Comment: For each row statement missing.

Comment: To improve your response rate, take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and, in particular, it's helpful to include the code in the question and give a more descriptive title. Cheers!